# Xamarin IOS background task on a schedule

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am writing a Xamarin application that needs to download and upload data on a schedule.
Currently the task is working fine on Android by using the Android Foreground Service along with the Notification Manager. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

BUT in IOS...
I can't figure out how to get a background service to stay running on a schedule (every 10 minutes) when the application is pushed to the background or the screen is off.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/
I can't use the Background Fetch because it runs when it feels like running and I need to run on a strict 10 minute schedule.
I can't use the Background Transfer Service because it only "starts" by the Background Fetch which is back to not running every 10 minutes.
I can't use the Remote Notifications because the app is doing the "push" to the service and not the other way around.

Since I am gathering GPS data, I tried to use the IOS GPS Location Manager Service but that only works if the device physically moves inside a 10 minute window and some of the devices do not move every 10 minutes YET we still want data from the device.

I tried to use a Background Task with the Expiration Handler but it dies after 5 minutes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `...only works if the device physically moves inside a 10 minute window...` Well, if you do not receive data, then you know the device did not move and can "fake" the data in on the server.... As far as background processing, that is just how iOS works... I have done some work on fleet and service location services and we handled it two ways, first if the driver's phone (i.e. not the vehicle, as we used Android dedicated GPS devices for that) do not report GPS for X period, we sub'd in placeholder data.

Comment: , if we ended up with X times Y amount of sequence placeholder data, we send a background notification to request the phone send an update, if that fails to get a device reply, send a foreground notification to the user to get them to respond via a custom notification and/or opening the app.

Comment: The short answer is you can't execute background tasks on a schedule on iOS. What data are you trying to get from the device?  For location you can use the suggestion above - if you haven't got data then you can assume the device hasn't moved (or has location turned off or isn't on the network or...).  For other data, perhaps you could use silent push notifications every 10 minutes to trigger a task?

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for the information. On Android I have it working great in that the Foreground service can call the Xamarin Essentials GPS location library on a 10 minute timer and logs it to a local database. It seems that IOS does not allow the app to "poll" the GPS on a timer but instead, the IOS app has to "listen" to GPS events. So when the device is not moving we get "gaps" in the data on IOS but not on Android.

Comment: @Paulw11 I know there are apps like timers / stop watches, email retrieval apps (not push notification), ect that users can install on IOS that seem to work in the background. Basically I need the device to "pull" down a json file every 10 minutes, add a new timestamp into the file along with the current location, and then upload the file to a server. Basic field data collection without much user interaction. Which is working perfect on Android but fails on IOS.

Comment: @goroth Beware on Android that it is very device specific on the latest API levels of if foregrounded services will be stopped, also on Android 9+ the rules of background processes is changing (much more iOS like)